# Is it possible to add sitefinity widget to my custom widget?

Tags: sitefinity

I'm attempting to create a custom widget in Sitefinity 11.  The goal is to display tabs on the page, with panels of content below each clickable tab.  I am using bootstrap to accomplish this which is simple enough.

My hope was to be able to add a Sitefinity placeholder to each tab, which would allow editors to drag and drop a widget, such as a content block to that tab.  But it seems that when I try to do this, the placeholder area never displays in the CMS, like it would if I had added a placeholder to a custom template.

Is this possible?

Here is a short code example:

```
<div class="container mt-3">
<!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li id="tab1" class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel1">@Model.Tab1Name</a>
    </li>
    <li id="tab2" class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel2">@Model.Tab2Name</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="panel1" class="container tab-pane active">
        @Html.SfPlaceHolder("Panel1")
        <p>here is text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="panel2" class="container tab-pane fade">
        @Html.SfPlaceHolder("Panel2")
    </div>
</div>
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put a SfPlaceHolder on a widget, it must be in your layout file (page template).

What you can do is to create a custom designer for your widget and put one or more content blocks in it, e.g. one for each tab you want to have.

Then in the view, you simply render the content.

https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/create-custom-designer-views-mvc

EDIT: To achieve this you need:

**Controllers / MyRichTextController.cs**

```
    public string RichText
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

**Views / MyRichText / DesignerView.Default.cshtml**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <sf-html-field class="kendo-content-block"
                   sf-images-settings="@SettingsHelpers.GetMediaSettings("Image")"
                   sf-videos-settings="@SettingsHelpers.GetMediaSettings("Video")"
                   sf-documents-settings="@SettingsHelpers.GetMediaSettings("Document")"
                   sf-model="properties.RichText.PropertyValue">
    </sf-html-field>
</div>
```

**Views / MyRichText / DesignerView.Default.json**

```
{
  "priority": 1,
  "components": [ "sf-html-field" ]
}
```

Another alternative could be to create a Layout widget with the above html structure and that will allow the user to put content blocks inside the areas of the layout.

You can just copy any of the existing layout widgets and work on that. Note, that with this approach you would probably have some css rules that hide all but the first tab panel, so you will need to have some additional css rules just for the backend in order to show all the panels so that users can drag widgets to them. That would make this approach a little bit more trickier.

Comment: In your first suggestion, you mention using "Content Blocks" in the designer, but you are not actually referring to a Sitefinity content block widget...correct?  You are talking simple text fields...please correct me if I'm wrong, as I don't see a way to use a content block widget in the designer itself.   It is our desire to use a content block widget within the tabs for ease of use for our non-coding editors.   It sounds as though your second solution may be the only way for this, but again, will require some work arounds for hiding and showing as you stated.

Comment: In my comment above, I should have said "It is our desire to use a rich text editor (preferably with image controls) within the tabs for ease of use...". If I can figure out how to do this, I think I can make my custom widget work.  I am attempting to use in my designerview: <sf-html-field sf-model="properties.MyHtmlField.PropertyValue"></sf-html-field> And in json file: "components" : ["sf-html-field"] but the rich text editor does not display.

Comment: Did you put priority: 1 in the json file? Something like this: 
{
  "priority": 1,
  "components": [ "sf-html-field" ]
}

Comment: Updated my answer above with code samples that work in v.11

Comment: Veselin, thanks so much!  I have it working now using your example.  I was close before your last response with the example, but I think I had a naming convention wrong with my json file.  Your example made me realize it.  Once I corrected that, it started working.  Your time is VERY appreciated!